# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm trying to iterate through a group of files in a folder on my local machine and upload only ones where the file names contain "Service_Areas" to my FTP site using using this code (Python 3.6.1 32 bit, Windows 10 64 bit):

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.ftpsite.org')
username = ('username')
password = ('password')
ftp.login(username,password)
ftp.cwd(username.upper())
ftp.cwd('2017_05_02')

for i in os.listdir('C:\FTP_testing'):
    if i.startswith("Service_Area"):
        local_path = os.path.join('C:\FTP_testing',i)
        file = open(local_path,'rb')
        ftp.storbinary("STOR " + i, open(file, 'rb'))
        file.close()
        continue
    else:
        print('nope')

ftp.quit()
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test1.py", line 32, in <module>
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + str(i), open(file, 'rb'))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think it has to do with your second element in `storbinary`. You are trying to open `file`, but it is already a pointer to the file you opened in line `file = open(local_path,'rb')`. So, try to use `ftp.storbinary("STOR " + i, file)`.