# Python 3.7 django app failed to start with unhandled exception

Tags: python, django, python-3.7

I'm running `windows 10 pro`

I just upgraded from `python 3.6.2 64bits` to `python 3.7 64bits` and my `django` app stopped working with an unhandled exception error:

```
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 224, in __init__
    provider = get_provider(package_name)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 351, in get_provider
    return _find_adapter(_provider_factories, loader)(module)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1384, in __init__
    self.module_path = os.path.dirname(getattr(module, '__file__', ''))
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 221, in dirname
    return split(p)[0]
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Anyone here seeing the same issue and got a solution to share?

Comment: [Possible duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135947/typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-io-bufferedreader)

Comment: Please post at least the FULL traceback.