# Don't understand this TypeError while attempting to parse JSON file

Tags: python, typeerror

I get the error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType` when I try to read and parse a json file. I checked for this error online and stumbled upon this link on stackoverflow -

[TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135947/typeerror-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-io-bufferedreader)

But the above looks like the same problem but the resolution doesn't work with my code.

Code below:

```
# function to parse the json file and extract useful information
def json_parser(file):
    print(file)
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        json_decode = json.loads(fp.read())
        pprint(json_decode)
        return json_decode

# script to read through the directories and parse json files

rootDir = 'projects/dataset'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print("Found directory: %s" % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
        fname1 = print("'" + fname + "'")
        # calling the json parser function defined above
        result = json_parser(fname1)
        print(result)
```

Traceback:

```
Error: File "test_json_parsing.py", line 15, in json_parser
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: @py_noob can you show us how you're calling `json_parser()`?

Comment: `fname1 = os.path.join(dirName, fname)`

Answer (score 1):

`fname1 = print("'" + fname + "'")` assigns `None` to `fname1` and not the string printed.  So, as the error indicates, `fname1` is of `NoneType` and cannot be opened.

EDIT Thanks @Jared Smith for clearing this up for me